# Can a clue giver let team know they are almost right?

Tags: taboo

Can a clue giver let his team know that they have the right word, but he wants a different form?  For example, the team players respond with “symphonic” and the word is “symphony”.  Can the clue giver say, “that word is right” and then gesture to keep trying other forms by rolling his hands?

Comment: For that specific case, the clue giver can say "noun form".

Answer (score 2):

I struggled to find a copy of the printed rules for this online, only various guide.  There is a [Rules summary on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/100834/rules-summary) that clear says -

> The Clue Giver cannot use hand gestures

So 'rolling his hands' is technically against the rules.

I also wouldn't say "that word is right". because in the example you gave it wasn't.   I can't see anything in the rules that says you can't say "that's almost right"

The important thing to remember is you playing a fun party game.   In games like this if a player becomes to strict and rules lawyering that it stops being fun.  If a player makes a minor rules violation then keep it fun and let it go the first time.  In the UK there is a radio show called "Just a Minute" which is a silly party game.  when players do minor things wrong the Host gives player "The benefit of the doubt" to let players get away with small things but that they will try to redress later.  I think this is good practice in all party games.

If you look at the rules queries for Taboo on [BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1111/taboo/forums/66) there are lots with 'Dispute' in the title.   Its a fun silly game and not worth a dispute about, Don't let the rules get in the way of just enjoying playing.